# Literal Types in Julia

Tags: types, julia

What is the best pattern to create literal types in Julia?

In Typescript, you can make types out of string literals:

```
type command = "start" | "end" | "pause";
```

In Julia, this would allow you to use multiple-dispatch with string arguments, making it easy to extend cases.

An example of this would look like

```
function process(::"start") 
    initialize()
    do_something()
    ...
end

function process(::"end")
    teardown()
    ...
end

function process(::"pause")
    temporary_pause()
    ...
end
```

Currently, I am using a workaround similar to this

```
struct CommandType{T}
end

CommandType(s::AbstractString) = CommandType{Symbol(s)}()

macro CommandType_str(s)
  return CommandType{Symbol(s)}
end

function process(t::CommandType"start")
  ...
end

function process(t::CommandType"stop")
  ...
end

function process(t::CommandType"pause")
  ...
end

process(command::String) = process(CommandType(command))

# Usage
process("start")
```

Is there a more succinct pattern I can use? Is it possible that literal types will be added to Julia in the near future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know the current practice is essentially what you have developed. To be concrete it is to use `Val` with `Symbol` argument. So your function signature would be e.g. `process(::Val{:start})` and you would call it with `process(Val(:start))` (of course you could use a utility function or macro to generate `Val(:start)` from a string as in your code if you wanted)

Answer (score 1):

I would take another approach to your problem, **don't rely on string or symbols to determine which function to use**, instead **write functions that have clear names**.

For example, your function is named `process()` and takes a `start` command. What I'm I processing? Do I do something with that command in the function?

Instead what if I wrote:

```
function start_service(# pass required arguments)
   ...
end
```

Sounds better, I know what I'm starting and the necessary arguments, if any, would make sense.

Later on, I decide I need to write data to a file, I now have to update the `Command`, perhaps, `write`?

```
function process(::CommandType"write",path::AbstractString,data)
    # What is being written? Error log? Data?
end
```

It would be cleaner to write:

```
write_data_to(path::AbstractString)
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing i managed to get without going crazy and without polluting the scope of hoisted symbols is:

```
module Extraction
@enum Type log_stats_by_author commits_by_author
end

function extract_git_stats(extraction_type::Extraction.Type)
...
end

extract_git_stats(Extraction.commits_by_author)
```

This also works with intellisense in Julia's vscode extension, solutions using Symbol/Val won't provide any autocompletion:

[image]